# Where can I find Facebook Wifi service specifications?

Tags: facebook, wifi, checkin

I'm trying to implement Facebook Wifi Checkin using a Raspberry Pi.

I'm using CoovaChili to catch user and redirect to my captive portal and everything is working great.

I tested some wireless routers that provide Facebook Wifi and they redirect me to this page, https://www.facebook.com/wifiauth/config?gw_id=NUMBER when I need to configure Facebook Wifi.

How can I generate this gw_id number?

I think there I need to register the client (raspberry pi) at facebook and get this number then I use this number to associate with some Facebook Page and then get checkin when someone try to connect to Internet.

I can't find any page, anywhere saying something about this gw_id number.

Thank you.

Comment: It existed on https://www.facebook.com/business/facebook-wifi but doesn't anymore.

Comment: Thanks @WizKid. I think that it's a TOP SECRET document. hehe